# MongoDB find operation query gives wrong result

Tags: php, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my mongodb find query:

```
db.getCollection('candidate').find({
    "$or": [
      {
        "email_id": {
          "$regex": {
            "regex": "^ranjit",
            "flags": "i"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mobile_no": {
          "$regex": {
            "regex": "^ranjit",
            "flags": "i"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "phone_no": {
          "$regex": {
            "regex": "^ranjit",
            "flags": "i"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "skill_name": {
          "$regex": {
            "regex": "^ranjit",
            "flags": "i"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "current_address": {
          "$regex": {
            "regex": "^ranjit",
            "flags": "i"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "first_name": {
          "$regex": {
            "regex": "^ranjit",
            "flags": "i"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

Above mongo db query return me wrong tuples. It returns tuples who doesn't contain "ranjit", but actually I want tuples who contain "ranjit".

Could you explain why it's returning wrong tuples and what is the correct query?

Comment: Why not use a wildcard text index?

Comment: What is the mongodb version?

Comment: mongo DB - 2.4.14

Comment: I want to use $regex in php to get results

Answer (score 1):

Your can try this

```
  //like '%ranjit%'
  db.getCollection('candidate').find($OR:[...{""email_id": /ranjit/},....])

  //like 'ranjit%'
  db.getCollection('candidate').find($OR:[...{""email_id": /^ranjit/},....])

  //like '%ranjit'
  db.getCollection('candidate').find($OR:[...{""email_id": /ranjit$/},....])
```

Using regex :

```
 db.getCollection('candidate').find($OR[... {"email_id" : {$regex : ".*ranjit.*"}},...]);
```

Comment: but i want to search in multiple field with $or condition.

Comment: but i want generate above query in php  and pass to mongo db to run

Comment: you can keep rest same only matching condition will change "email_id":{
                            "$regex":{
                                "regex":"^ranjit",
                                "flags":"i"
                            }
                        }

Comment: for regex :  db.getCollection('candidate').find($OR[... {"email_id" : {$regex : ".*ranjit.*"}},...]);

Comment: for regex : db.getCollection('candidate').find($OR[... {"email_id" : {$regex : ".*ranjit.*"}},...]) it is right.now its give me result but it case sensitive.how can i make it case Insensitive

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search multiple fields for same query, you can add a new field in the document, which contains concatenated values of all the fields and then make regex search on that field. 
So the document with fields 'name', 'email', 'skillName' would change to:

```
{
    name: 'Ranjit', 
    email: 'ranjit@someDomain.com', 
    skillName: 'MongoDB Administration', 
    gist: 'Ranjit|ranjit@someDomain.com|MongoDB Administration'
}
```

You can easily make a regex based search on field `gist`. If you execute query on multiple fields, then a compound index will required to speed up the search, however in this case only one index will be required(for `gist`).

Here is the query that you would be required to fire for the search operation:

```
db.getCollection('candidate').find({"gist": /ranjit/})
```